# I wonder why 2 variables can't enter into js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am working on Ajax-php livesearch programming. I want to input 2 params in Html input boxes but JS can't receive those values. Why?

My HTML

```
<form class="category 1" name="search" action="display.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">
    <select id="category" class="category" onchange="showUser1()" title="choose the language you want">
        <option value="">카테고리를 선택하세요</option>
        <optgroup label="고속 검색 : 시작하는 단어가 매칭됩니다.">
            <option value="3d">3D</option>
            <option value="dorl">돌란드 사전</option>
            <option value="term">영한 표준용어사전</option>
            <option value="kcd">표준질병코드</option>
            <option value="ind">인덱스</option>
            <option value="toc">목차</option>
            <option value="coupling">연결고리</option>
            <option value="fig">Figure</option>
            <option value="tab">Table</option>
    </select>
    Input:
    <input type="text" name="search" id="qstr" onkeyup="showUser1()"> Input:
    <input type="text" name="search" id="pstr" onkeyup="showUser1()">
</form>
```

And My js code as like below.

```
function showUser1(str) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5 
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
    var q = document.getElementById('qstr').value + "&p=" + document.getElementById('pstr').value;

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "./livesearch_" + category + ".php?q=" + q, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Exactly, 1 select-option param - good entering-, qstr ID variable - good entering-, and pstr ID variable - don't work=

why doesn't pstr work??
[image]

chrome console window as below.
[image]

Comment: You should be encoding the query string value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Please describe what exactly does not work. Does `document.getElementById('pstr').value` not return the correct value? What happens if you do a `console.log(q)` at the end of the `showUser1()` function?

Comment: You do not cancel the form submission.....

Comment: He is not submitting the form.

Comment: Somehow I don't think you'll need to account for IE5 or IE6 anymore. You may want to look for a more current example of AJAX implementation - or use a library like jQuery.

Comment: Your code works, so really unclear what the issue is.  What is the error in your console?

Comment: I am using ajax, so submit does't need. pstr value isn't going to js code.

Comment: It works for me when I copy the code into a snipplet.

Comment: It works for me too. Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ap7ubkhx/

Comment: Why you but I succeed in working?? I am using xampp 32 bit 7.2.3 v.

Comment: I use the web browser of chrome. late version

Comment: q is undefined because it is inside of the function and not global..... your console testing makes zero sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a unique name

```
Input: <input type="text" name="search" id="qstr" onkeyup="showUser1()" > 
Input: <input type="text" name="search-2" id="-pstr" onkeyup="showUser1()" >
```

Comment: Why would that make any difference?

Comment: as he is accessing the fields using `getElementById()`, the `name` attribute will not matter for the AJAX request, but the two fields should still have two different names, because it will matter after submitting the form to `display.php`

Comment: Even with the same name, it is not an issue with the Ajax call and it is not really an issue with form submission since it is just two entires in the querystring. This answer does nothing really for the OPs problem.

Comment: Jim, that doesn't

Comment: is the array you're forming affecting the ajax?  {search: [1, 2]},

Comment: There is no array with the Ajax call above

Comment: Is there a value attribute for the input fields?  The js is calling for it but where is it set?

Comment: <input type="text" name="search-2" id="-pstr" onkeyup="showUser1()" > => attributes are type, name, id, onkeyup event. I input text only as attribute type.

Comment: because it's silly to have two inputs with the same name. What is the goal in doing that?

Comment: Different names don't work! name variables are useful in php not js.

Answer (score 0):

I have done another code as a trick in js code.

Instead of below code,

```
var q = document.getElementById('qstr').value + "&p=" + document.getElementById('pstr').value;
```

that is

```
var q = document.getElementById('qstr').value+" "+document.getElementById('pstr').value;
```

I replaced "&p=" with " ".
That works.

[image]

After I did explode function in php, I gained 2 params from 2 inputs. That is my best i think.

Of course White space is not apt for search usage.
Maybe "+" will be good for multiple variables in php.

```
var q = document.getElementById('qstr').value+"+"+document.getElementById('pstr').value;
```

Thanks a lot for sincere advice!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i see your console has the values for variables: pstr and qstr, so will this work for you:

```
var q = qstr + "&p=" + pstr;
```

so are you hoping for finally ...php?q=cd&p=ab